# Compile a function to run it in other machine without resolving address dependencies

Tags: c, gcc, raspberry-pi, arm

Im developing a bare metal OS for raspberry pi 1. The main idea of this OS is a simply kernel that will be able to run a function created in other machine and send it to the raspi. The function will use functions that were compilated with the kernel and that reside in memory.

I want to know how can I compile a function that when I will insert the payload in memory in a determinated address it will be able to call system functions and use the data that are defined in the function code.

```
void function()
{

    while (1)
    {
        uart_puts("Hello\r\n");
    }
}
```

This is my link.ld file and the function will be loaded at __binary_function:

```
ENTRY(_start)
SECTIONS
{
    /* Starts at LOADER_ADDR. */
    . = 0x8000;
    __start = .;
    __text_start = .;
    .text :
    {
        KEEP(*(.text.boot))
        *(.text)
    }
    . = ALIGN(4096); /* align to page size */
    __text_end = .;
    __rodata_start = .;
    .rodata :
    {
        *(.rodata)
    }
    . = ALIGN(4096); /* align to page size */
    __rodata_end = .;
    __data_start = .;
    .data :
    {
        *(.data)
    }
    . = ALIGN(4096); /* align to page size */
    __data_end = .;
    __bss_start = .;
    .bss :
    {
        bss = .;
        *(.bss)
    }
    . = ALIGN(4096); /* align to page size */
    __bss_end = .;
    /*Allocating memory for the heap*/
    __heap_start = .;
    . = . + 0x1000000;  /*4MB Heap section*/
    __heap_end = .;
    __binary_function = .;
    __end = .;
}
```

My idea is that the kernel will receive the payload via UART and then execute it. The payload must be able to call system functions such us the UART functions and access to the data that is define inside it.

I want to do this automatically with arm-none-eabi-gcc (GCC Toolchain for ARM architecture) that works like GCC and avoiding harcoding the system functions in the payload source.

Thanks!

Comment: It's common to use software interrupts to call kernel functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it using the hardcoding the kernel functions in the payload:

```
void (* uart_puts)(char *) = (void(*)(char * )) 0x0000000000008248;
```

I get the 0x0000000000008248 address from the .map file generated in the compilation of the kernel.